# How to set custom offset to "FloatingActionButtonLocation" in the scaffold, in flutter?

Tags: flutter

So recently FloatingActionButtonLocation was introduced and it has four values all for bottom alignment. I want it at the top, halfway below the app bar. But I couldn't figure out how to set a custom offset. The official documentation is also scarce on this.

Answer (score 7):

This is against material design guidelines.But you can do this by changing `scaffoldGeometry.contentBottom` to `scaffoldGeometry.contentTop` from original source code.Below code should work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;


class HomeHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  HomeHeaderState createState() {
    return new HomeHeaderState();
  }
}

class HomeHeaderState extends State<HomeHeader> {

  static const FloatingActionButtonLocation centerDocked = _CenterDockedFloatingActionButtonLocation();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: widget._scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('duh'),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation:centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {

      },),
      body: new Container()
    );
  }
}
class _CenterDockedFloatingActionButtonLocation extends _DockedFloatingActionButtonLocation {
  const _CenterDockedFloatingActionButtonLocation();

  @override
  Offset getOffset(ScaffoldPrelayoutGeometry scaffoldGeometry) {
    final double fabX = (scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.width - scaffoldGeometry.floatingActionButtonSize.width) / 2.0;
    return Offset(fabX, getDockedY(scaffoldGeometry));
  }
}

abstract class _DockedFloatingActionButtonLocation extends FloatingActionButtonLocation {
  const _DockedFloatingActionButtonLocation();
  @protected
  double getDockedY(ScaffoldPrelayoutGeometry scaffoldGeometry) {
    final double contentBottom = scaffoldGeometry.contentTop;
    final double appBarHeight = scaffoldGeometry.bottomSheetSize.height;
    final double fabHeight = scaffoldGeometry.floatingActionButtonSize.height;
    final double snackBarHeight = scaffoldGeometry.snackBarSize.height;

    double fabY = contentBottom - fabHeight / 2.0;
    if (snackBarHeight > 0.0)
      fabY = math.min(fabY, contentBottom - snackBarHeight - fabHeight - kFloatingActionButtonMargin);
    if (appBarHeight > 0.0)
      fabY = math.min(fabY, contentBottom - appBarHeight - fabHeight / 2.0);

    final double maxFabY = scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.height - fabHeight;
    return math.min(maxFabY, fabY);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! However, did less complicated, put FAB on 25% and 75% of the width.

Answer (score 2):

don't use the built-in FAB, but rather a stack with your own circular button.  inside your scaffold's body you can do this:

```
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[

      Container(
        // whatever your main content is
      ),

      Positioned(
        top: 5.0,
        right: 200.0, // or whatever
        child: MyFAB,
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

and then MyFAB can be this:

```
class MyFAB extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

      color: Colors.blue,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () => {},
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
        child: Container(
          width: 45.0,
          height: 45.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            size: 25.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and you can now position the FAB wherever you want it using the Positioned widget in the Stack.